# do php file at a time according to database

Tags: php, mysql, web

I'm creating a website and in my website I have a MySQL database. In the database there is a table that has two property "date" and "time". I want to run a php code on a date and time according to records of table, automatically. How can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried anything?? Show some codes.

Comment: I have no idea to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see three options, listed here in order of difficulty to implement, easiest to hardest.

1. Create a script that is scheduled to execute every now and then (exact timing would depend on your needs for accuracy), which checks the database to see if there are any items in there that should have been executed in the time span since it's last execution. If there are, execute them.
2. Write a daemon application/script to monitor your database, and execute the tasks when needed. This one is not all that different from #1 except that it wouldn't require scheduling or manual triggering. That could be handled within the application/script itself.
3. Create a script that checks the database for changes, and schedules/reschedules/removes any tasks accordingly. This script would then be scheduled to execute every now and then and/or be executed manually by the application that manages the database.

Comment: I think first approach can solve my problem. but I'm fearing that running a script at short periods(for example each second) can pressure the server.

Comment: If your timing has to be accurate down to a second, then a script executed as a cron job would not work. In most systems the lowest trigger time of a cron job is a minute. - The only viable option for that scenario would be the second option I list.

Comment: which of them is the faster way?(suppose that I can use cron job)

Comment: The fastest thing to implement is the first method. It's simplest, and thus easiest to create. - As for performance. If you are only checking and triggering events ever minute, then the performance difference is inconsequential; too small to be a concern.

Answer (score 0):

Write a php script (that queries the database and runs the script) powered by crontab (for periodically running your 'query'-script) in a shell (on linux)

Comment: with crontab I can run a script at specific time. but I don't want to run script priodically. according to your answer, I should do cron each second!